# How to remove duplicate values in an array without using unique method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a program where values in an array are [1,2,46,5,8,2,8], now I want to remove duplicate values but without using unique method of Ruby. Can anyone help with the logic of doing it? I want to make a unique array.

The code that I am using is may be not absolute to the question which is why I am getting the answer to first two situations but not the last one. Here is the code :

```
 def uniq(array)
    i=0
    while i < array.length
        if array[i] == array[i+1]
          puts ""
        else
        puts i
        end
        i += 1
    end
   end

   uniq([5,5,5,5])
   uniq([1])
    uniq([1,2,46,5,8,2,8])
```

Comment: Just some ideas. You could convert to a set then back to an array. Or iterate through the array, pushing each element to another array if it's not already in it.

Comment: [so] is not a code-writing service. You need to show us the code you have written and ask *specific* questions about *that code*. Please, read how to construct a [mcve], [ask], and the [help]. Why don't you want to use `uniq`? It is *exactly* the method you *should* be using, because it does exactly what you're asking. If `uniq` isn't working for you, then there's probably something wrong with how you defined the equality relations for your objects, and the correct fix is not to avoid `uniq`, but rather to fix your broken equality.

Comment: Hi Jorg!! Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the intersection or union:

```
arr = [1,2,46,5,8,2,8]
# => [1,2,46,5,8,2,8]
unique_arr = arr & arr
# => [1, 2, 46, 5, 8]
```

Comment: ...or union ([Array#|](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-7C)).

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to convert to a Set which will remove the duplicates, then convert back to an array. First `require 'set'` (in the Standard Lib) then, either of these:

```
Set.new([1,2,3,3]).to_a
# => [1, 2, 3]

# Does the same thing without passing the array to the Set constructor
[1,2,3,3].reduce(Set.new, &:add).to_a
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: `'require set'` also adds `Array#to_set` which is another nice way to convert an array to a set.